# iterate through homemade button coords as fast as possible in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datatable

Is there a better/faster way to temporarily store 30-40 rectangle coordinates than creating a datatable and iterating through with a loop?

```
    Dim optionbuttons As New DataTable
Private Sub addcolumns()
    optionbuttons.Columns.Add("name", GetType(String))
    optionbuttons.Columns.Add("x1", GetType(Integer))
    optionbuttons.Columns.Add("y1", GetType(Integer))
    optionbuttons.Columns.Add("x2", GetType(Integer))
    optionbuttons.Columns.Add("y2", GetType(Integer))
    optionbuttons.Columns.Add("noCode", GetType(Integer))
    optionbuttons.Columns.Add("level", GetType(Integer))
End Sub
```

Any suggestions of better ways to temporarily store this data would be most welcome. The options are pulled from an sql server by way of linq-sql.

In JavaScript I used to use an associative array to store these in but I'm not sure if that's possible in vb.net

Comment: you could use a dictionary http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating a class to represent my rectangle:

```
Public Class MyButton
    Public Sub New(ButtonName As String, x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, y2 As Integer, ButtonNoCode As Integer, ButtonLevel As Integer)
        Me.Name = ButtonName
        Me.UpperLeft = New Point(x1, y1)
        Me.BottomRight = New Point(x2, y2)
        Me.NoCode = ButtonNoCode
        Me.Level = ButtonLevel
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property UpperLeft As Point
    Public Property BottomRight As Point
    Public Property NoCode As Integer
    Public Property Level As Integer
End Class
```

Then I would populate a list from the datatable:

```
Public Function PopulateListFromDataTable(dt As DataTable) As List(Of MyButton)
    Dim ReturnValue As New List(Of MyButton)
    For Each r As DataRow In dt.Rows
        ReturnValue.Add(New MyButton(r("name"), r("x1"), r("y1"), r("x2"), r("y2"), r("noCode"), r("level")))
    Next
    Return ReturnValue
End Function
```

This gives you all of the niceties of having a class with named properties, and they're all in a list which can easily be iterated with:

```
For Each b As MyButton In MyListOfButtons
```

Comment: Thanks DWRoelands, that looks like a slick solution. I'm having a little trouble with the function though, I don't really want to feed it a datatable, I'd rather feed it individual variables per record as I gotta adjust the coordinates before feeding them to the class. If that makes sense. I'm trying to convert it but I'm not sure if I'll manage. Anyways, I'll be in touch, and thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
   Public Function PopulateList(name As String, x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer, x2 As Integer, y2 As Integer, nocode As Integer, level As Integer) As MyButton

    Return (New MyButton(name, x1, y2, x2, y2, nocode, level))

   End Function
```

This correct?